# Why this query don't work in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Why this query:

```
$data = Category::find(3)->articles->where('publish', '1')->paginate(5);
```

doesn't work? The `select` query: `$data = Category::where('publish', '1')->paginate(5);` works.

Version laravel: 5.1. In table `categories` there are one-to-many relationships with table `articles`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`articles` returns collection and `articles()` returns `relation`. You can use `where` on `relation` and not on `collection`.

change

```
$data = Category::find(3)->articles->where('publish', '1')->paginate(5);
```

to

```
$data = Category::find(3)->articles()->where('publish', '1')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: @razumov_alex Glad I could help. You can accept this as an answer so it may help future user to find answer for same problem.